# Stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I find the query of a stored procedure? Is there any way to view it?

Comment: That depend on what tool are you using?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio, under the database tree, choose `Programmability | Stored Procedures`. Just right click on the procedure name and click modify.

But the database role will also affect your action.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this one simple way is

```
sp_helptext 'Your_SP_Name'
```

or

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('Your_SP_Name'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id)     
FROM syscomments 
WHERE [text] LIKE '%%' 
AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsProcedure') = 1 
GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(id)
```

Try This Its Worked...